# Why the installed version of the program runs different from the one in debug mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, time

I created a program that sends a bunch of text in to the COM port on the speed 9600. In debug mode the program sends all the data and than the COM port is closed. Bit if I create a installer project and than install it on the same machine it doesn't send the last symbols. It closes the port earlier than all data is transmitted. So my question is: Is the debug exe file slower or is it somehow slowed down by the IDE (Visual Studio)?

Also adding a `Sleep(100);` between the last transition command and the port closing line the problem disappeared.

Comment: A debug exe is generally slower than a release, and running it under the debugger slows it down further.

Comment: If a release build wan't faster, then there would be no reason to do one (debug symbols are external in the .pdb file)

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question.  By submitting a [MCVE], maybe we could see:  What code closes the port ... something you wrote?  or is the 'send' action asynchronous (usually desirable for performance) and thus possibly still running when the thread exits?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: I disagree. The OP has asked a clear and answerable question. They can now take the knowledge learned and move on to the next step in their diagnostics. We're not here to just fix everyone's bugs for them outright. This is not a debugging website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observations correspond with a program written incorrectly, showing signs of a bug that is currently only detectable with a *release build*.

Release builds tend to run faster, as they are created at an enhanced optimisation level and with various debugging utilities turned off. They are designed for maximum production performance at the expense of development-time debuggability. Creating an installation package evidently created a release build (which makes sense).

This increased performance in turn affects the timing of your program. If you were accidentally relying on there being a long duration before the port was closed, giving your program enough time to transmit all its data only by chance, then when this process speeds up your bug becomes observable. There is no longer enough time for the data to get through. Adding a `Sleep` simulates the slower execution of the debug build, thus almost certainly confirming the existence of a timing bug.

This is good news! You have strong evidence of where the bug is and the form it takes. Now all you have to do is fix it!